# Should F# type annotations be removed when refactoring?

Tags: f#, refactoring, type-inference

In cases where I'm writing a function before it is used anywhere, I'm finding it useful to add type annotations to its parameters. This means I can autocomplete on its values and (especially as an F# newbie) won't get confused by unexpected type inference.

However, once the function is finished, I'm tempted to remove the parameter's type annotations because they're ugly. Does this sound like a reasonable thing to do?

I expect that it might depend on what kind of function I'm talking about. For example it might make sense for a private function, but not for a public one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it depends on lots of factors.  Here are a few arguments in favor of leaving the annotations:

1. Type annotations can arguably serve as a form of compiler-checked documentation.
2. Don't modify working code without a good reason.
3. Some type annotations may be necessary for compilation, in which case perhaps it makes sense to leave all of them rather than remove only the unnecessary ones for consistency.

However, on the other hand, there are also some compelling reasons to remove them:

1. The compiler may actually infer more general types, in which case you can reuse functions in a broader set of contexts.
2. Your code will be more concise, which you may find to be more readable.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, my personal style is to maintain annotations of public module interfaces using fsi files, and erase most annotations within fs module implementation files (unless they are required by left-to-right type inference).  With this scheme it is a big deal to change the module interface, and a lesser deal to change its implementation.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no advantage to it. You could say it makes the program easier to change afterwards, or it looks better, but in practice it never works out.

Most likely you'll just end up retyping the annotations anyway, for exactly the same reason you added them in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I think, an important argument here is that *removing type annotations change the meaning of the sources*.

Indeed, let us assume there is a source code: `let f (arg: MyType) = arg.ToString()`.
The source restricts `arg` to be of type `MyType`. If any client code attempts to pass an argument of another type, it will simply not compile.
This also applies to **Unit Tests**. With type annotation, it is easy to see that all Unit Tests call `f` only with arguments of type of `MyType`.

If the type annotations are removed, type inference work unrestricted, but the tests are not ready, they *still* only test it with `MyType`.

Therefore, **removing type annotations must be associated with changing the Unit Tests**, likewise any other refactoring. If you are ready to improve tests, go for it. Otherwise you may be asking for trouble, especially for a large codebase.

Comment: That's a really interesting point, I'd not thought of it from the TDD perspective. Writing tests first will mean that I won't need to annotate when I only want to help myself.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of personal style; I would take them out. As you get better at F# coding you may find you have to go through the annotation phase less often.